# Hide description when lyrics is visible, and the same inversely (and a possible bug?)

Tags: javascript, html

Here's this pretty simple snippet below.

When you run it, you can see the album description, if you click on the `span`, the song lyrics appears, and the description disappears. If you click on it again, you'll see my problem:  both the description and lyrics becomes visible and after that clicking on the span does nothing any more.

But what I'd like to achieve, is to make the code work like with that bug(or whatever that is), if the song lyrics is visible, then hide description, if description is visible, hide the lyrics

I've tried some variations with other `if` , `else if` or `else` statements, also tried some things in the `for` loop, but I just couldn't make it work.

How could I achieve that?

```js
function showlyrics(){
    document.getElementById("albuminfo").style.display="none";
    var lyrics=document.getElementById("songlyrics");
    lyrics.style.display = (lyrics.style.display === 'block' ? 'none' : 'block');

    if(lyrics.style.display==="none"){
        document.getElementById("albuminfo").style.display="block";
        //whatever;
    
    //If I write anything after setting albuminfo a block display (UNCOMMENT "whatever;" TO SEE) and I close it, it's actually working as I want it, but I have no idea why, if you could explain this too, I'd appriciate it
        
    }
    //I don't know if this part is necessarry, so I'll just leave it here
    var hideotherlyrics = document.getElementsByClassName("lyrics");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < hideotherlyrics.length; i++) {
    hideotherlyrics[i].style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("songlyrics").style.display="blocK";
}
}
```

```css
#starslyrics{
    position:absolute;
    top:3%;
    right:40%;
  font-size:25px;
  font-weight:bold;
    
}

.hover:hover,.hover a:hover{
    border-radius:5px;
    border:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color:red;
    color:white;
}
.lyrics{
    display:none;
    position:relative;
  margin-top:50px;
    font-size:18px;
}


#albuminfo{
    text-align:justify;
    width:400px;
    font-size:18px;
  margin-top:50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="lyrics">
<p id="albuminfo">

THIS IS THE <strong>ALBUM DESCRIPTION</strong><br><br> IF THIS IS VISIBLE, THE SONG LYRICS SHOULDN'T BE

</p>
<p class="lyrics" id="songlyrics">
THIS IS THE <strong>SONG LYRICS</strong><br><br> IF THIS IS VISIBLE, THE ALBUM DESCRIPTION SHOULDN'T BE

</p>

<span  class="hover" onclick="showlyrics()" id="starslyrics">Click here</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define and set initial values out of the `showlyrics()` function. Otherwise, they don't store the display status and every time you click on the function, it resets the previous status.

```js
var description = document.getElementById("albuminfo");
var lyrics = document.getElementById("songlyrics");

description.style.display = "none";
lyrics.style.display = "block";

function showlyrics(){
 if(lyrics.style.display === "block"){
     description.style.display = "block"; 
            lyrics.style.display = "none";
 } else {
            description.style.display = "none"; 
            lyrics.style.display = "block";
        }
}
```

```css
#starslyrics{
 position:absolute;
 top:3%;
 right:40%;
  font-size:25px;
  font-weight:bold;
 
}

.hover:hover,.hover a:hover{
 border-radius:5px;
 border:none;
 cursor:pointer;
 background-color:red;
 color:white;
}
.lyrics{
 display:none;
 position:relative;
  margin-top:50px;
 font-size:18px;
}


#albuminfo{
 text-align:justify;
 width:400px;
 font-size:18px;
  margin-top:50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="lyrics">
<p id="albuminfo">

THIS IS THE <strong>ALBUM DESCRIPTION</strong><br><br> IF THIS IS VISIBLE, THE SONG LYRICS SHOULDN'T BE

</p>
<p class="lyrics" id="songlyrics">
THIS IS THE <strong>SONG LYRICS</strong><br><br> IF THIS IS VISIBLE, THE ALBUM DESCRIPTION SHOULDN'T BE

</p>

<span  class="hover" onclick="showlyrics()" id="starslyrics">Click here</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple problem with your logic, i took the liberty to clean up the markup a bit.

```js
function showlyrics() {
  var albume = document.getElementById("albuminfo");
  var lyric = document.getElementById("lyrics");


  if (albume.style.display == "none") {
    albume.style.display = "block"
    lyric.style.display = "none"
  } else {
    lyric.style.display = "block"
    albume.style.display = "none"
  }
}
```

```css
#starslyrics {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3%;
  right: 40%;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.hover:hover,
.hover a:hover {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

#lyrics {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#albuminfo {
  text-align: justify;
  width: 400px;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="lyrics">
  <p id="albuminfo">
    THIS IS THE <strong>ALBUM DESCRIPTION</strong>
    <br>
    <br>IF THIS IS VISIBLE, THE SONG LYRICS SHOULDN'T BE


  </p>
  <p id="lyrics" id="songlyrics">
    THIS IS THE <strong>SONG LYRICS</strong>
    <br>
    <br>IF THIS IS VISIBLE, THE ALBUM DESCRIPTION SHOULDN'T BE


  </p>
  <span class="hover" onclick="showlyrics()" id="starslyrics">Click here</span>
</div>
```

Oh and the style object doesn't store the styling defined in your css file, but the inline ones, but using else without condition is a work around :)